# How do you get the pointer of something you dereferenced?

Tags: c++

The pointer points to a struct which contains an array. How do I get the memory location of each element of the array in the pointer?

```
ptr->array[a]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `&ptr->array[a]` will give you a pointer to element `a` within `ptr->array`.

Answer (score 0):

and also `ptr->array+a`, becuase of pointer arithmetics. but use @Vaughn Cato way for readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the address-of operator (&) to get the address of a variable. (As in `&ptr->array[a]`.)

However, since `ptr->array` is already an address, you can also use the syntax `ptr->array + a`.

Comment: ptr -> array is not an address. -> is the dereference operator. ptr -> array is a value

Comment: `ptr->array` returns the address of the array (the address of the first item in the array). The address of an array is indeed an address.